# How can I make this code more DRY

Tags: python

From [web2py example 33](http://www.web2py.com/examples/default/examples) we see:

```
db.purchase.insert(buyer_id=form.vars.buyer_id,  
   product_id=form.vars.product_id, 
   quantity=form.vars.quantity)
```

but I think there should be some way to make this less repetitive. perhaps this?

```
db.purchase.insert(**dict( [k = getattr(form.vars, k) for k in "buyer_id product_id quantity".split()]))
```

Comment: how is that repetitive? ... the first example is more pythonic I think(simplicity)

Comment: you can pass a dict to `insert()`, you can pass a list of dicts to `bulk_insert()` and you can filter the dict using `_filter_fields`

Answer (score 6):

For me, DRY means 1) not repeating actual code, and 2) (and more important) not repeating information; i.e. there should be one place that each item of information exists.

In this instance, you're really just repeating a pattern, and I think that's fine.  The second example is much harder to read; why complicate it just to save a few characters?

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid repeating `form.vars`:

```
vars = form.vars
db.purchase.insert(
    buyer_id=vars.buyer_id,  
    product_id=vars.product_id, 
    quantity=vars.quantity)
```

There is still some repetition, but I think it's better to leave it with some repetition rather than making your code hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

<s>if those 3 things are all there is you could do</s>

db.purchase.insert(**form.vars)

otherwise I think that the original code is plenty dry

but i guess you could do

```
to_insert = {"product_id":form.vars.product_id,"quantity":form.vars.quantity,"buyer_id":form.vars.buyer_id}
db.purchase.insert(**to_insert)
```

which is similar to your second example but is more readable and simple (some of the tenets of python)

Comment: `**form.vars` would not work. The `**kwargs` syntax applies to dicts, not to object property names.

Comment: oh you are absolutely correct...my bad.. not sure what I was thinking (anyway ... fixed now)